# Custom IsAny and IsUnknown generic based on type assignability(compatibility) table

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I tried to create `IsAny` generic based on [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#any-unknown-object-void-undefined-null-and-never-assignability).

And my `IsAny` generic seems to work fine.
But when I use it in another generic(`IsUnknown`) it is broken:

```
const testIsUnknown2: IsUnknown<any> = true; // problem here, must be false
```

But when I change `IsAny` generic to commented one, - it works fine again. So why is it happening? Because I do not see any difference in both `IsAny` generics, but it seems my generic is not working inside other generics.

```
// type IsAny<T> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? true : false;

type IsAny<T> = unknown extends T ? (T extends object ? true : false) : false;
const testIsAny1: IsAny<any> = true;
const testIsAny2: IsAny<unknown> = false;
const testIsAny3: IsAny<string> = false;
const testIsAny4: IsAny<object> = false;

// unknown is only assignable to two types: unknown and any
type IsUnknown<T> = unknown extends T ? (IsAny<T> extends true ? false : true) : false;
const testIsUnknown1: IsUnknown<unknown> = true;
const testIsUnknown2: IsUnknown<any> = true; // problem here, must be false
const testIsUnknown3: IsUnknown<object> = false;
const testIsUnknown4: IsUnknown<number> = false;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your `isAny<any>` yields `boolean`, which means both of these assignments will pass:

```
const testIsAny1: IsAny<any> = true;
const testIsAny2: IsAny<any> = false;
```

For the other `isAny` definition, `testIsAny2` fails.

Regarding your definition of `isAny`, it fails because the conditional type `T extends object ? true : false` returns both alternatives for `any`. I couldn't find any documentation about this, but you can fix it the same way you can prevent conditional types from distributing over unions, by surrounding both sides with square brackets ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)):

```
type IsAny<T> = unknown extends T ? ([T] extends [object] ? true :  false) : false;
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQJIGcCCA7SAeAKgPlALygAMosAHuLGgCZKgAUAjKAGSjYCUoA-BAE4BXeAC5QAMwCGAGySwA3AFgAUCAgx4ydFjyFQgtAGs0AewDuaMpWp0OvRtitVa9EwCMAVrADG4e+CFRCRk5bjEpWQUVKDhEVAwcfCIDY3NLCmdbRz4GAG1sAF0nG3pc9y9fIr4A4VBwkNgw4MilZRVvEzQkPypurQwmMX6sSQwkgWFWjq6e2D74yAAmIYXMUchxiLlWlQBvdVjsOb8iYbWx0ABfFTVQO9AAPR49g-gj7r0zlNMLfGvVMD3R7PZT7GJvY6fVblHzgP43QH3J4vcEcSGnVYANxMAEsaPCAUDgSiNGiPhjtJgDDRYOIcWhYPirgiicjQa8ySc4pS0IJpNICbckSCwaT3lyzgzMbB+ILEXc2dFScgAKpGH5oRJ6b5pYouOw5M66DIlCbwPhbII1Rp1ZrbFQkw7ouJq1IWc4bZmEoFs0VO8ku9VpKlB35eoUKkUc8VQ10azAw3xy1lR1ExjFx4PYvHJn2psXO1WhzXU2n0xm54WOiEBotuzW8-mVyPVzmx4uYKUy3CXUAsvNAA)

Comment: Yep, i know about conditional distributive types. But is any union? I mean distributive conditional types as it says in docs is for unions... Seems any is like a union of all types and distributed here too.

Comment: @valerii15298 You're absolutely right, I mistakenly assumed `T` was a `boolean` here, not `any`. It appears to be just special behavior for `any`, which can be prevented in the same way as preventing distribution over unions.

Comment: And your unknown type actually does not work: `const testIsUnknown2: IsUnknown<any> = true;`

Comment: @valerii15298 Ugh, it's not my day :-) Copied it from a larger type function for all primitive types, but there turned out to be a sneaky `IsAny` at the beginning. Adding the `IsAny` makes it longer than your definition, so I'll just remove it from the answer.

Comment: I decided to use this one as it does not depend on others: `type IsUnknown<T> = unknown extends T ? ([T] extends [null] ? false : true) : false;` and works just fine:)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually with `IsAny`.

You've noted that `true: IsAny<any>`, however, `false: IsAny<any>` also!

You've touched on an aspect of conditional types that can be rather counterintuitive.

I'll give this example:

```
type Extends<T, U> = T extends U ? true : false;
```

We have:

```
Extends<'a', 'a' | 'b'> =:= true
Extends<'c', 'a' | 'b'> =:= false
```

Nothing surprising so far.

What might be surprising is this:

```
Extends<'a' | 'c', 'a' | 'b'> =:= boolean
```

When we have `T extends U ? …`, if there is subtype of `T` that is a subtype of `U` *and* a subtype of `T` that is *not* a subtype of `U`, then the resulting type is the union of both branches.

Comment: Yep, that is due do distributive conditional types. Seems any acts here as union of all types.